# Is there a way to modify MDX frontmatter in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, mdxjs

I am using `gatsby-plugin-mdx` with Gatsby. I've added a `draft` field to my frontmatter and I would like to override its value to always be false when `NODE_ENV` is `"production"`. Note that `gatsby-plugin-draft` doesn't seem to modify the MDX AST and is incompatible with `gatsby-plugin-mdx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in `onCreateNode` method.

YOu can do something like:

```
// onCreateNode.js
const { createFilePath } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem')

module.exports = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === 'Mdx') {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: 'pages' })
    const isProduction = ... // TODO: implement

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'draft',
      value: isProduction?  false :  node.frontmatter['draft'],
    })
  }
}
```